# Can drush show list all available modules?

Tags: drush

With yum you can do `yum list available ...`, and know the name of the package you want to install.

For example, there is the Mime Mail module in Drupal. What name should I use with `drush dl`, mime_mail, or mimemail?

So does drush have something like `yum list available`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, drush can't do that.

Why should it when you can [see the entire list](http://drupal.org/project/modules/index) yourself on drupal.org.

[image: SS]

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know the name to use with drush dl.

Comment: @ericj The name drush used is the machine name, which also is used in the URL on drupal.org. fx http://drupal.org/project/commerce is the url for the Drupal Commerce project, to dl it use `$ drush dl commerce`

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can. based on this [feature request](http://drupal.org/node/1389460), I build the functionality, and created a [sandbox module](http://drupal.org/sandbox/Letharion/1833420).

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think you should use the last segment of the URL
When I was trying to find out what to use for the "Redirect 403 to User Login" module
Example: http://drupal.org/project/r4032login

use: drush dl r4032login

Comment: Why was this answer down voted? It is correct. The OP asked, in comments "Thanks, but I want to know the name to use with drush dl"

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_list_of_drushable_modules(){
$url = "https://www.drupal.org/project/project_module/index";
$content =  get_url_data($url);
$start = '<div class="view-content">';
$end ='</ol>';

$start_i = strpos($content,$start);
$content = substr($content,$start_i);

$projects = explode("</li>",$content);
$new_projects = array();

foreach($projects as $i => $project){
    $st = '<a href="/project/';
    $strlen = strlen($st);
    $st_i = strpos($project,$st);
    $project = substr($project,$st_i+$strlen);
    $project_character = str_split($project);

    $new_project = "";

    foreach($project_character as $char){
        if($char == '"') break;
         $new_project .= $char;
    }

    $new_projects[] = $new_project;
}

return $new_projects;
}

function get_url_data($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers. Explanations of why and how are worth much more than code that happens to work - or not.

Answer (score -1):

No drush does not have this feature

Comment: would you like to elaborate more on this?